# MVC5 which Helper only update main content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5 I have a classic layout with the menu to the left and a big main content area to the right.

The menu has 3 buttons. They are supposed to update the main content each with a different view(index, index2, index3).

When I try with @Url.Action() the whole page gets reloaded. I only want the view to be rendered in the `@RenderBody()`

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'">Index</button>
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index2", "Home")'">Index2</button>
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index3", "Home")'">Index3</button>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="col-main" class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well"></div>
        <div id="renderBody">
            @RenderBody()
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax if you want to update only part of the same page.

Comment: Makes sense thanks alot. I will get right to it. I guess I tunnelvision to hard on the helpers here. My bad.

Comment: What about the html i get back? How to I get it into RenderBody()? I can set it on a div, but is there a more best practice way to use RenderBody()?

Comment: You can look at the using an Ajax helper [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) although I prefer just plain jquery. Not sure what you mean by _ get it into RenderBody()_? `RenderBody()` is just a 'placeholder' for the main content. You would need a container element (e.g. div) to define where to add the html returned by the ajax call

Comment: I have tryed to set the returned html into "col-main" and "renderbody". Both gets rendered, but both have some offset which most be because of my bootstrap, but that's another thing I guess.
My question is would you wrap RenderBody() in another div or use "col-main" ? See my UPDATE 1 please.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the full html and the css. I just use the default `<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">@RenderBody()</section>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this ...

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,HttpMethod = "GET"})
```

you can provide your right panel ID as target area where you can render the views which you want...
I hope this will helpful to u.

Comment: I had to add two things before it worked, but thanks alot for getting me on the right track.
1) In the controller i should return a "PartialView" instead of a "View"
2) I had to add "@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"